# Passive voice in english grammar

Tags: passive-voice

What I wanna know here is if I'm able to say this phrase:

> They have been moving me to other regions, ever since.

in this way (I guess it's passive voice):

> I have been moved to other regions, ever since

without making a grammatical mistake.

When I first formulated this phrase, I didn't have this doubt. But when I looked at it again, I got this questioning and by searching it on google, I couldn't find any types of phrases like this "passive one", so I really think it is a mistake. What I find tho, are phrases like:

> I have been moving to other regions, ever since

that have a completely different meaning.

Comment: Yes, Lucca, you used the passive voice and it was the correct choice. It shows that you had no choice about the moves. There is much paranoia about using the passive voice. It does result in much horrible writing, but a writer's strategy should be to select the BEST subject and BEST verb for their idea - if that means a passive voice is needed, so be it. When reviewing your drafts it is wise to examine where you have used the passive voice. That should prompt the question: did I REALLY choose the best subject and verb for this idea? Be cautious but not afraid of using the passive voice!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely grammatical, and correctly preserves the meaning of "someone else moving you", rather than you moving voluntarily.  You don't specify the subject (which is often the reason for the passive voice), but if you wanted you could say:

> I have been moved to other regions **by them**, ever since

However, let's say you want to keep the progressive "moving" to preserve the sense of constant motion.  We can say something like,

> I have been **being moved** ever since.

but, while (probably) grammatical, I think we can agree this sentence is pretty awkward.  A better option would be:

> I have been **kept moving** ever since.